# How to deal with an optional argument to an observable?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have an Angular component that fetches data from a service with `service.getItems`. Sometimes, the service call is plain, in other cases, a filter is required. This filter can be set through a component property `filter`.

I am convinced I am missing something fundamentally, but I cannot get it to work properly. Either I can get it to accept the filter, or ignore the filter, but not react on the presence of the filter.

Any suggestions to modify the code below to actually work?

```js
@Component({}
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <!-- Items are shown async -->
    {{ items | async }}
  `
})
export class MyComponent {

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Initialize the filter observable with a null value
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  constructor(private service) {
    this.filter = null;
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Filter observable to hookup the filter value to the service
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  filter$: Subject<Filter> = new Subject<Filter>();

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Service call to fetch items
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  items$: Observable<any[]> = this.filters$.pipe(
    switchMap(filter => this.service.getItems(filter));
  );

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Allow filter with
  // <my-component [filter]="myFilter">
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  @Input()
  set filter(filter: Filter) {
    this.filter$.next(filter);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`. If you want the `filter$` to emit on initialization a null value, you'd need to use `BehaviorSubject`. As of the moment you assign `items$` to the `Observable`, `this.filter$` has not emitted anything so the whole Observable hasn't run yet.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
       <!-- Items are shown async -->
       {{ items$ | async }}
  `
})
export class MyComponent {

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Initialize the filter observable with a null value
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 constructor(private service) {
 }

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Filter observable to hookup the filter value to the service
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 filter$: BehaviorSubject<Filter> = new BehaviorSubject<Filter>(null);

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Service call to fetch items
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 items$: Observable<any[]> = this.filters$.pipe(
   switchMap(filter => this.service.getItems(filter));
 );

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Allow filter with
 // <my-component [filter]="myFilter">
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 @Input()
 set filter(filter: Filter) {
   this.filter$.next(filter);
 }
}
```

Here's a stackblitz you can play with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ce8jrw

EDIT: I cannot explain why `Subject` didn't work as I also tried `this.filter$.next(null)` in the `constructor`.

Comment: Aren't emits discarded when there's no subscribers yet? Which would be the case if the observable gets async bound, which means that during construction time, there is no subscription yet?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% here but I believe that because you are not subscribing to the filter explicitly you are not able to watch it for changes effectively. I would add

```
this.filters$.subscribe( res => {
  res.pipe(
    switchMap(filter => this.service.getItems(filter)
  )
})
```

This should listen for the creation of the filter and then fire `this.service.getItems(filter)`

Good luck!

Comment: The OP is using Async pipe so there's no need to subscribe there.

Comment: Ah my bad. Thanks @ChauTran